# Неверно отрабатывает код при тестировании. Задача о шахматной доске и ладье (со Stepik)

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Проблема:** Неверно отрабатывает мой код. Прошу помочь - почему решение не верное? Где я ошибаюсь?

**Задача со степика (Stepik):**

> "Даны две различные клетки шахматной доски. Напишите программу, которая определяет, может ли ладья попасть с первой клетки на вторую одним ходом. Программа получает на вход четыре числа от 1 до 8 каждое, задающие номер столбца и номер строки сначала для первой клетки, потом для второй клетки. Программа должна вывести «YES», если из первой клетки ходом ладьи можно попасть во вторую, или «NO» в противном случае."

**Пример теста, который не проходит:**
координаты клетки 1: 2 1
координаты клетки 2: 1 1.
На выходе NO, а должно быть YES.

**Комментарий к моему решению:** Мой код проверяет входят ли вообще координаты в нужный диапазон. Проверка х_1 больше 1 одновременно с тем что х_1 меньше или равно х_2 одновременно с тем что у одинаковые. Я это сделал для того чтобы проверить что  для того чтобы попасть в точку х_2;у_2 можно только по х. вторая проверка проверяет тоже самое только с у.

```
y_1 = int(input()) #столбец первой клетки

x_1 = int(input()) # строка первой клетки

y_2 = int(input()) # столбец второй клетки
x_2 = int(input()) # строка второй клетки

if (x_1 >= 1 and x_1 <= x_2 and y_1 == y_2) or (y_1 >= 1 and y_1 <=y_2 and x_1 == x_2):
 
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Comment: Я закончил обновлять ответ и отредактировал ваш текст, так как за закрытие вашего вопроса стали голосовать. Посмотрите, на редакцию на будущее. Также рекомендую: "Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Полный (все строки) текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. У вас `x_1 <= x_2` и `y_1 <=y_2` условия неверные.
   Вполне допустима первая клетка 8 8, а вторая 8 1, например.
2. Раз уж есть проверка на `>= 1`, то надо и на `<= 8` в этой логике.
3. Лучше разделить проверку на правильность координат и на одинаковость, так как у вас нет ещё и проверки на вхождение числа в диапазон при равенстве (например, x1=x2=9 пройдет вашу проверку).
4. И проверка на совпадение первой и второй клетки желательна тогда.

Исходя из этого, я бы такое условие сделал для "YES":

```
if (1 <= x_1 <= 8 and 1 <= y_1 <= 8 and not (x_1 == x_2 and y_1 == y_2))\
        and (y_1 == y_2 or x_1 == x_2):
```

Comment: Последняя пара условий записывается проще: `(x_1 == x_2) != (y_1 == y_2)`.

Comment: Первые два условия не нужны. В задаче сказано что координаты попадают в нужный диапазон.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, да, всё так, спасибо. Моя логика: вопрос от начинающего и вопрос по конкретно его коду. Соответственно: 1) "записывается проще" - оно не проще, оно короче. Вам, возможно, не видно этого с вашего уровня, но мне задуматься пришлось на десяток секунд над идеей. Автору ещё больше нужно будет. Проще все же у меня в ответе, с функциональным разделением проверки правильности ввода и проверки самой возможности. 2) Раз уж было у автора, то показал, как нужно делать правильно.

Answer (score 1):

попробуй

```
if x_1 == x_2 or y_1 == y_2:
    print("YES")
```

в комментах к задаче есть схема как ходит ладья, все поле не надо проверять
кстати, в следующей задаче у Антона Мельникова классное решение на форуме, мое любимое за весь курс

Comment: Als, +1 я поставил, но больше, чтобы помочь набрать 50 баллов для возможности комментировать в дальнейшем. На самом деле ответ мог как-то помочь, но на вопрос "почему решение не верное? Где я ошибаюсь?" не отвечает. Так что это пока больше на комментарий похоже. И код надо в ответе выделять (я отредактировал сейчас).

Comment: `(1, 1), (1, 1)` - возвращает истину. Чего быть не должно. В один ход нельзя остаться на месте.